# Disable Checkbox in pageblocktable

Tags: visualforce

I am looking to disable checkbox based on matching value in field of "rep type" which is in User object and a field of "Doctype" which is in Account object

for example:

Reptype is red and Doctype values are Red,Yellow, Red + yellow.

Now I am trying to disable chechbox where Reptype field value matching values in Doctype
In this case , checkbox disabled for red and Red + yellow.

I know we can use disabled attribute where we can different combination to disable. But I want to get dynamically by matching values in both fields.

Please let me know If anyone have any difficulty in understanding.

**Added from comment below:**

> Now my scenario is I need to disable from picklist values. Here is my
>   sample code.See here spec is picklist where It has NRP,N
>
> `rendered="{!if(contains(spec,doc.acc.Specialization__c),'false','true')}"`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you ever used formula functions that work also in Visualforce? Looks like this one is a candidate for [`CONTAINS`](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CONTAINS), possibly also with `TEXT` if they're picklists.

Comment: Maybe you could post some code?

Comment: Yes I have a picklist where I have want to disable checkbox whose values is in that picklist. My problem is as I am using contains If In my picklist If values are NRP then both N and NRp records checkboxes are disabling.If I select N then it is behaving properly. I want to understand what should I do.?

Comment: See here spec is picklist where It has NRP,N rendered="{!if(contains(spec,doc.acc.Specialization__c),'false','true')}"

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your visualforce page has an object called **"o"** related to `User` and `Account` you should try something like this:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox disabled="{!!CONTAINS(o.account.Doctype,o.user.Reptype)}" value="{!o.checkbockFieldName}" />
```

Take a look of this samples of [advanced use of formulas](http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/useful_advanced_formulas.htm)

Comment: Thanks for that, Now my scenario is I need to disable from picklist values. Here is my sample code.See here spec is picklist where It has NRP,N rendered="{!if(contains(spec,doc.acc.Specialization__c),'false','true')}"